# How to give a combined title for subplots?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I want to give a combined title to my subplots, instead of titling each plot individually.
e.g;

```
for pl=1:4
      subplot(2,2,pl)
      title('Test') 
end
```

gives me this:[image]

If I use this:

```
figure
title('Test') 
for pl=1:4
      subplot(2,2,pl)

end
```

I don't get any title.

I want my output like the following:[image]

Comment: Try the `suplabel` submission on MATLAB FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a small trick. You can do the following to spawn a figure with multiple subplots.

```
h = figure 
for pl=1:4
    subplot(2,2,pl)
end
```

After this you have to set the `NextPlot` property to `'add'`. Do this:

```
h.NextPlot = 'add';
a = axes; 

%// Set the title and get the handle to it
ht = title('Test');

%// Turn the visibility of the axes off
a.Visible = 'off';

%// Turn the visibility of the title on
ht.Visible = 'on';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since you have already defined a handle to the figure. You should use that. Use h.Name = 'Finite Horizon'. If you use figure again, of course it will open another figure window.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the [Bioinformatics toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/bioinfo/) you can use `suptitle`. Otherwise, there's the excellent [`suplabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel) on the MathWorks File Exchange that can do this and more.

Answer (score -3):

This is my version of the solution, print this in Command Window in Matlab:

```
clear all
close all
clc
name={'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'};
for k = 1:4
    subplot(2,2,k);
    title(name(k));
end
```

---

[image: Result]

*I hope this helps. Best regards.*

Comment: The OP wants an **overall** title over the figure. This labels all subplots individually. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: In fact, my decision is wrong, sorry.

Comment: It isn't a problem. Next time, make sure you read the question before answering. You can see what the expected output is from the OP and what you have provided does not match.